# Retroceder dos fragments a la vez

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo un activity con dos FrameLayout, cada uno con un fragment.
Pero al hacer un backpress primero el fragmentA vuelve a su estado anterior, y tras otro backpress el fragmentB vuelve a su estado anterior.

Quiero que al hacer backpress los dos FragmentA y FragmentB vuelvan a su estado anterior a la vez.

Aquí el código:

```
    mFragmentService.replaceAndAddToBackStack(FragmentA.newInstance(), R.id.container_top);
    mFragmentService.replaceAndAddToBackStack(FragmentB.newInstance(), R.id.container_bot);


    public void replaceAndAddToBackStack(Fragment fragment, @IdRes int idRes) {
           mFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(idRes, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName())
                    .commit();
}
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navegación atravez del backstack en la actividad:

```
/**
 * Recursivamente navega a través de los fragmentos anidados para una entrada al backstack.
 *
 * @return <code>true</code> si se realizó un pop
 * @see <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/39524096">Recursive PopBackStack</a>
 */
public static boolean recursivePopBackStack(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    if (fragmentManager.getFragments() != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragmentManager.getFragments()) {
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
                boolean popped = recursivePopBackStack(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());
                if (popped) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (recursivePopBackStack(mFragmentManager)) {
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Y para volver atras sería algo como hacer dos veces esto desde la actividad o desde el fragmento:

`mFragmentManager.popBackStack();`